# background-image in <div>-tag not showing up

Tags: php, css, html, background-image

im outquestioned. I just wanted to develop my own gallery, but then I already failed at the very start: Displaying an image as a background in a `<div>`. I have turned my code upside down, searched the web, searched stackoverflow, though I'm not able to solve the problem.

Here's my code:

HTML/PHP

```
<div class="imageholder" style="background-image:url(<?php echo $picture->thumbPath; ?>);"></div>
```

CSS

```
.imageholder {
        width: 150px;
        height: 150px;
        float: left;
        background-size: fill;
        background-position: 50% 50%;
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

I'm iteration through an array of `$picture-objects`. Each object has a `thumbPath` for its' thumb image. the paths are correct. checked them multiple times.

Here's the output of Firebug:

```
<div class="imageholder" style="background-image:url(./users/basti/img/20130825155015-tb-From Peth to Darwin/thumb/20130825155015-tb-DSC_0316_REZ.jpg);"></div>
```

I already thought of the path having the wrong format, though I'm using the same file paths on an other project where everything works. even displaying the same picture as a `background-image` of a `div-tag` ;) Hilarious, isn't it?

Do you have any idea what's wrong with my code? Thanks!

Comment: You're using relative path, make sure you're HTML output (file) and `users/` folder are on the same level.

Comment: they are, as I said I'm using the same paths as above in another file, where everything works fine!

Comment: The url doesn't point towards your picture. If I use a placeholder, for example http://placekitten.com/150/150 , everything works as expected. You can check in your developer console what url it tries to load.

Comment: the webconsole of ff told me css ignores the param background-image because it's incorrect. :/

Comment: Your path contain spaces(20130825155015-tb-From Peth to Darwin/thumb/) ? try to replace them by underscores

Comment: Just tried out and you're right. spaces won't work :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there are some space characters in your image path, Try to put your path in quote:

```
url('./users/basti/img/20130825155015-tb-From Peth to Darwin/thumb/20130825155015-tb-DSC_0316_REZ.jpg');
```

As an alternative, you can convert the spaces to `%20`, simply by [`str_replace()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php):

```php
background-image:url(<?php echo str_replace(' ', '%20', $picture->thumbPath) ?>);
```

([`rawurlencode()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php) is the way to encode URL, but in this case all the *forward slashes* will be converted.)

Comment: well thats even easier :) better than editing the other end of my sourcecode. EDIT: about your edit: the path in my filesystem is already ~spaceful~, so I'd rather go with the quotes

Answer (score 0):

My path contained spaces. Just deleted them and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

```
style=" background-image:url(<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/image/project1.png);
```

Write this code before path `<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/`

Comment: style=" background-image:url(<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>